# What should NOT be shared in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I've written my website using Django. Since I'm a huge fan of open source, so (like a lot of people do with their websites), I decided to create a repository for my website. Right now, I have it so my sqlite3 database is not in the repository, and that my secret key is hidden. I have 2 questions:

1) Are there any other files I should NOT include in my repository?

2) Is it safe to include the sqlite3 database? I have a blog, and that's the only thing using the database *that I'm aware of* but I intend to add users to my website at a later date. Is the Admin Interface username and password in the sqlite3 database? Is there any other sensitive information in the sqlite3 database that I should know of?

Thanks!

Comment: Admin belongs to users and yes he is included in the db, additionally sessions (if you use the DB for sessions), groups and permissions are also included. The rest is defined by your project (in terms of sensitive data).

Comment: So I shouldn't include any DB stuff in the repo?

Comment: Why would you even want to? Everything necessary to create and populate the database should be available via the migrations. There shouldn't be any need to included it. Apart from anything else, anyone wanting to actually deploy your site should be using a real RDBMS rather than sqlite.

Comment: You should probably not include your db, as anyone interested in the repo can start fresh and create their own, unless you have a need for sharing your specific data with people interested in your repo. Also, if this is the same site you are using in production and not a development site, make sure to remove sensitive data from your `settings.py`, such as the `SECRET_KEY` and any usernames or passwords you have included.